# jQuery: Iterate through selector IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, refactoring, iteration

I have some jQuery code that is quite redundant. I want to refactor it to avoid to duplicate it for every 30 numbers. Each pin-Small ID has a pin-Big ID with the same number. I want to have a code that works for every ID with a higher number (#pin-Small2, #pin-Small3, #pin-Big2, #pin-Big3 and so on ...). It's written in CoffeeScript, but I provide it as a JS version also.

**I don't find a start to iterate through these numbers**. Can u help me? I would be very thankful if you'd do so, dont't mind if it's in JS or CS. Thanks so much in advance! :)

**CoffeeScript**

```
$('#pin-Small1').on
    mouseenter: ->
        $(@).hide()
        $('#pin-Big1').addClass "enabled"

$('#pin-Big1').on
    mouseleave: ->
        $(@).removeClass "enabled"
        $('#pin-Small1').show()
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#pin-Small1').on({
  mouseenter: function() {}
}, $(this).hide(), $('#pin-Big1').addClass("enabled"));

$('#pin-Big1').on({
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).removeClass("enabled");
    return $('#pin-Small1').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: You should use `class` on these elements to group them. Can you post your HTML code so we can see how to traverse from `#pin-small` to `#pin-big`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing your HTML may really help as it could change this answer, but assuming that your HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id="pin-Small1" class="small" data-related-big-pin="pin-Big1"></div>
<div id="pin-Small2" class="small" data-related-big-pin="pin-Big2"></div>
...
<div id="pin-Big1" class="big" data-related-small-pin="pin-Small1"></div>
<div id="pin-Big2" class="big" data-related-small-pin="pin-Small2"></div>
```

You could use data attributes like this:

```
$('.small').on
    mouseenter: ->
        $(@).hide()
        var bigPinId = $(@).data("related-big-pin")
        $('#' + bigPinId ).addClass "enabled"

$('.big').on
    mouseleave: ->
        $(@).removeClass "enabled"
        var smallPinId = $(@).data("related-small-pin")
        $('#' + smallPinId).show()
```

So we use classes to bind the mouseenter/mouseleave functions then read data attributes to find which elements they interact with.

Comment: Great, that works best for me! Clever solution, thank you very much for your help! (I edited the code, since there was a little mistake in the data-related-small-pin values: they ware pin-Big instead of pin-Small)

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS classes and related selectors... HTML:

```
<div id="pin-Small1" class="pin"></div>
<div id="pin-Small2" class="pin"></div>
<div id="pin-Small3" class="pin"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.pin').each(function() {
    // do something with each element, e.g. to hide them all:
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Another solution for this, but does not fit to my markup! Nonetheless, thank you!